# Add column not belonging to the table to use FK?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have a little problem with some tables where I want to have valid data and prevent invalid data from being inserted. My idea was to use FK for this but I don't have the needed column inside the table I would need it. Should I add it, although it's not really belonging there or what should be done in this case?

Tables:

**box**

```
----------------------------------------
box_id (PK)   box_type_id (FK->box_type)
          1                            1
          2                            1
----------------------------------------
```

**box_type**

```
---------------------------------
box_type_id (PK)   width   length
               1      40       30
               2      50       40
---------------------------------
```

**box_pos**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
box_id (PK, FK->box)   box_pos_id (PK)   item_id (FK->item)   amount
                   1                 1   item1                    10    
                   1                 2   item2                   100
                   1                 3   item3                   500
                   2                 1   item2                    50
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**item**

```
------------------------
item_id (PK)  otherstuff
item1           yadayada
item2           yadayada
item3           yadayada
------------------------
```

**item_box_type**

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
item_id (PK, FK->item)   box_type_id (PK, FK->box_type)   amount_full_box
item1                                                 1               500
item1                                                 2               600
item2                                                 1               400
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I have a box with a certain type. For this box I have box positions (different items with amount inside the box) and I have another table which has some information like how much of this item makes a full box.

What I want is to prevent data being inserted into box_pos which doesn't have an entry inside item_box_type but I don't have the box_type on the positions because it belongs to the box. Is there a better than adding the box_type to the box_pos, which would violate normalization rules as it doesn't depend on the box_id/box_pos_id key but only on the box_id.

Of course I could use triggers, an insert/update trigger on the box_pos to check if a combination of box.box_type_id and box_pos.item_id exists in the table item_box_type and a delete trigger on the item_box_type to check if there is still a row inside the box_pos with that combination but I like to avoid triggers if possible because their performance impact is bigger and they are pretty bound to the rdbms in use.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to prevent data being inserted into `box_pos` which
>   doesn't have an entry inside `item_box_type`...

If you don't like `box_type_id` in your `box_pos`, you can restructure your `item_box_type`, like so:

```
--------------------------
item_box_id           (PK)
item_id        (FK) UNIQUE
box_type_id    (FK) UNIQUE
amount_full_box
```

And restructure your `box_pos` by replacing `item_id` with `item_box_id` referencing the `item_box_type` table, thereby achieving your needed constraint.

---

The simplest solution, though, is that `box_pos.box_type_id`.

Comment: The first solution would mean that I have a sh..load of redundant data because amount_full_box and other information would be always the same for every item_box_id of that box_type_id/item_id combination. That would be a bigger risk for invalid data and the table would need quite some inserts/updates/deletes while it's pretty much static data. And box_type_id inside the box_pos just doesn't feel right but if that's the best solution It will be the way to go, just thought it was wrong and I'm missing some better solution.

Comment: @aLpenbog It seems I did not get quite well what you said about redundancy.. The restructured `item_box_type` will have no trouble in having redundant `box_type_id/item_id` combination because of the `unique` constraint.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Looks like an interesting solution. But I think it's better to have the box_type_id in the box_pos then instead a surrogate key, I wouldn't want to move the item_id away.